# Project Points To Clip Space Manually SceneKit

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

I couldn't find any documentation on this, so I decided to as a question. I'm using SceneKit to render a few cubes, and when I tap the cubes, I want to go to a 2D screen. I thought it would be really cool if when you tap the cube, it constructs a 2D shape which gets bigger and fills the screen for a transition. I've done something like this before in OpenGL, and I just converted the cubes points to clip space, then constructed the shape there. 
To do that, you need the modelView and projection matrices and the position of the cubes points. Is there any way to do this in SceneKit? Can I get the points of geometry and the modelView and projection matrices of the camera?

Any insight would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every node has a `transform` and `worldTransform` property, so it's easy to create a `model` and then a `modelView` transform. Or you can just use conversion utilities such `-[SCNNode convertPosition:fromNode:]`. Finally `SCNCamera` exposes `-projectionTransform`.

Or you can replace all that by using `-[SCNSceneRenderer projectPoint:]`.